# WP adding styles from home folder

Tags: css, wordpress, styles

Hi I need to add stylesheet but not in functions like wp_enqueue_style. I am working on gulp and I need to add styles from home/css/style.css direction. How can I do this?

Comment: where is your home directory relative to your theme?

Comment: I need to add styles from my "/" directory. Not them directory

Comment: AFAIK, that's not possible. Your css has to be accessible using HTTP protocol and whatever is outside the server is not accessible using HTTP

Comment: You say you "need to".  Why do you need to? I doubt that's actually true, and would definitely not be the "WordPress Way".

Comment: So please tell me how can I use gulp with Wordpress to convert my scss to css file. Do I just have to make folders in my theme and then in gulp file just change the directory?